# Umbraco throwing a 500 for /umbraco

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6

Have a weird issue with Umbraco. It's throwing a 500 error for /umbraco. Custom errors are off in the Web.config but I'm still seeing the IIS default custom error page. There is nothing in UmbracoTraceLog related to that error. Is there anything I can do to debug?

Comment: You need to post a specific error message for us to be able to help you, have you looked in the event viewer for the machine the site is running on to see the error?

Comment: I would check the App pool settings. The .Net Version and the user context the site is running in. The default is IIS_IUSRS

Answer (score 0):

Not providing the specific error message will make this difficult to help. To try and recreate I made a new environment and moved an existing Umbraco project to it and got a 500 error and corrected it by updating the connection string, AppPool user and permissions on the folders.

First step, I would advise to check that your permissions.
See [Umbraco Permissions](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/files-and-folders/permissions) for the file and folder permissions needed.